# Automatically initialize member field for string literal types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

If I have the classes

```
class Foo {
  type: "foo"
  constructor(public id: number) {}
}

class Bar {
  type: "bar"
  constructor(public id: number) {}
}

type SomeUnion = Foo | Bar // (x : SomeUnion).type will have the type "foo" | "bar"
```

Constructing an instance of `new Foo(1)` will yield `{ id: 1 }` at runtime, but I would like to get `{ id: 1, type: "foo" }`.

A simple solution is of course to type the string constant twice, by assigning it in the constructor for example with `this.type = "class_name"`.

However, this is non-ideal since I need to type the same string constant twice. It's not a huge deal, but it's the kind of thing one could forget and lead to bugs.

Is there a way to auto-create a member of the object with the same value as the string literal?

Comment: You want the field`type` both to be of type `"class_name"` *and* to be initialized to the value `"class_name"`. I'm asking because I'm not 100% certain that you've not just confused type declarations and field initializations. (And the one answer you've got sets the type to `string`.)

Comment: Yes, it's important that the type is a string literal, and not a generic `string` in order to use it for union types elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's concentrate on this code:

```
class Foo {
  type: "foo"
  constructor(public id: number) {}
}
```

If the compiler option `strictNullChecks` is `false`, then `type: "foo"` implicitly also allows setting `type` to the values `undefined` and `null`. I hope the need to explicitly initialize the field to a value other than `undefined` is obvious.

---

So let's move on with `strictNullChecks` set to `true`. In this case, the only value that can be assigned to `type` is `"foo"`. It looks like what you're hoping to have some way to get the compiler to perform the following reasoning:

> `type: "foo"` says the field named `type` must be of type `"foo"`. Therefore, only the value `"foo"` can be assigned to it. Consequently, I should emit code to automatically initialize it to `"foo"` because there's no other value that can be assigned to it.

The problem is that TypeScript 2.x even with `strictNullChecks` currently allows fields to start with the value `undefined` even if assigning `undefined` is not valid. Let me put this explicitly: even though you cannot *assign* the value `undefined` to `type`, the field `type` can *start* with the value `undefined` (if you do not initialize it). This is not deemed an error. This is how TypeScript is currently designed. There is an [issue report about this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8476), with some people arguing it is a design flaw in the language.

At any rate, the compiler does not perform the desired reasoning above. **For now, one way or another, you will have to repeat the same value as part of the string literal type and as part of the initialization of your `type` fields.**

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do what you are looking to do. You still have to type out the string literal twice, but they are typed out in close proximity, so you would be less likely to forget if the class type ever changes to update both values.

```
class Foo {
  type: "foo" = "foo"
  constructor(public id: number) {}
}

class Bar {
  type: "bar" = "bar"
  constructor(public id: number) {}
}
```

Comment: As concise as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

If "it's important that the type is a string literal, and not a generic string in order to use it for union types elsewhere in the program" then you should have a type for that union, let's say:

```
type MyType = "foo" | "bar";
```

And then:

```
class Foo {
  type: MyType = "foo";
  constructor(public id: number) {}
}

class Bar {
  type: MyType = "bar";
  constructor(public id: number) {}
}
```

You can also have a common base class:

```
class Base
  type: MyType;
  protected constructor(type: MyType) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}

class Foo extends Base {
  constructor(public id: number) {
    super("foo");
  }
}

class Bar extends Base {
  constructor(public id: number) {
    super("bar");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about?

```
class Foo {
    type: string;
    constructor(public id: number) {
       this.type = "class_name";
    }
}
```

Comment: If the type is a generic string, then you can't have things like union types of string literals.