# Typescript Tagged Union Types

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I want to discriminate some logic according to what interface my function receives. To do this I'm attempting to use tagged union types, e.g.,

```
someFunction(arg: TypeA | TypeB): void {
    if (arg.kind === "TypeA")
    {
        // do this
    }
    else
    {
        // do that
    }
}
```

where

```
interface TypeA {
    kind: "TypeA";
    propertyA: string;
}

interface TypeB {
    kind: "TypeB";
    propertyB: string;
}
```

But if I want to call this function, Typescript complains if I don't provide a value for kind, i.e.,

```
let typeA: TypeA;
typeA = {propertyA: ""}
someFunction(typeA);
```

with

```
TS2322: Type '{ propertyA: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TypeA'.
  Property 'kind' is missing in type '{ propertyA: string; }'.
```

So I don't understand how tagged types work if I have to implement the tag (`kind` in the example above) every time I want to discriminate. I can only assume I'm using them wrong?

Comment: Typescript will **not** generate code for initializing `kind`, you have to provide that value yourself. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554662/automatically-initialize-member-field-for-string-literal-types-in-typescript

Comment: @artem That's where I get confused in trying to understand the value of tagged types. How are they any different to defining the property `kind` on the interface? What's the point in providing the string literal (`TypeA` and `TypeB`) on the interface?

Comment: Also if I have to define `kind`, why not just define a class and use `instanceOf`?

Comment: With tagged union types, if you have a `switch` or `if` statement with branches for every possible value, you can make compiler to check that all cases are handled. For example, if you turn on `--noImplicitReturns`  and remove `case "circle"` from `area()` function in  [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#tagged-union-types), you get 'Not all code paths return a value' error.

Comment: I think the big value of tagged unions is that you don't have to use assertions, which are fragile, or maintain your own user-defined type guards. You just create some unique field (doesn't have to be `kind`) and the compiler can follow type narrowing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a type guard to do this. They allow you to tell the type of an argument by the value or existence of one of it's properties.

```js
function isTypeA(arg: TypeA | TypeB): arg is TypeA {
    return (<TypeA>arg).propertyA !== undefined;
}

function someFunction(arg: TypeA | TypeB): void {
    if (isTypeA(arg))
    {
      arg.propertyA;
    }
    else
    {
        arg.propertyB
    }
}
```

You can read more about them [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and check a working example [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20TypeA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20kind%3A%20%22TypeA%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20propertyA%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20TypeB%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20kind%3A%20%22TypeB%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20propertyB%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isTypeA(pet%3A%20TypeA%20%7C%20TypeB)%3A%20pet%20is%20TypeA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20(%3CTypeA%3Epet).propertyA%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20someFunction(arg%3A%20TypeA%20%7C%20TypeB)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(isTypeA(arg))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(arg.propertyA)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(arg.propertyB)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AsomeFunction(%7B%0D%0A%20%20kind%3A%20'TypeA'%2C%0D%0A%20%20propertyA%3A%20'A'%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AsomeFunction(%7B%0D%0A%20%20kind%3A%20'TypeB'%2C%0D%0A%20%20propertyB%3A%20'B'%0D%0A%7D)%3B).

Comment: This was what I started doing, but then I thought about the scenario that I may want to add `propertyA` to interface `TypeB` sometime in the future. As soon as I do this, the behaviour of my code would break and there wouldn't be any way to pick this up unless I also remembered that I had to update function `isTypeA`. I figured using union types would provide greater type safety, but they seem quite polluting if I have to start implementing `kind` all over the place just to satisfy type safety.

Comment: Aaaah, wait. I guess adding `propertyA` to `TypeB` wouldn't mess things up as you're casting to `TypeA` in `isTypeA`.

Comment: Asserting, not casting, but yeah that allows it not to break. They are usually meant to be used in situations where you get such info from the server and you want to differentiate between them. It's really just doing if(obj.property) at runtime, but allows you to keep type safety while doing it.

Comment: I can tell you're not used to Typescript yet :) I'm happy my answer was of help to you. :)